# A Docker image for running enRoute OSGi framework?

Tags: osgi, bnd, bndtools, enroute

I want to try and run enRoute inside a Docker container but cannot seem to find any Docker images. Can anyone suggest the location of an image?

Comment: This is not a suitable question for StackOverflow. Please try the osgi-dev mailing list: https://mail.osgi.org/mailman/listinfo/osgi-dev

Answer (score 3):

OSGi enRoute uses [Bndtools](http://bndtools.org). There you can export an bndrun file to an executable JAR (see the [Base Tutorial](http://enroute.osgi.org/tutorial_base/050-start.html) and especially [deploying](http://enroute.osgi.org/tutorial_base/700-deploy.html)). You therefore only need to have a Java 8 image. This is a non-trivial task because Oracle is rather annoying concerning their copyrights but there is on `ggtools/java8` image. Therefore, to run an OSGi enRoute executable JAR on Docker, you can use the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM                            ggtools/java8
MAINTAINER                      pkriens@gmail.com
CMD                             java -jar test.jar
ADD                             test.jar test.jar
```

You can then build and run as follows:

```
$ ls
Dockerfile  
test.jar          
$ docker build .
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                        TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
<none>                            <none>              491dc47dbee6        About a minute ago   174.8 MB
<none>                            <none>              0e3b6c01e0b6        5 weeks ago          176.2 MB
ubuntu                            latest              1c9b046c2850        7 months ago         187.9 MB
ggtools/java8                     latest              dcdcbb7229ba        8 months ago         168.5 MB
$ docker run 491dc47dbee6
Welcome to Apache Felix Gogo    
g! eval:eval 3+4+5+6+7+8+9
42.0
```

If this works for you then an Application note for the OSGi enRoute website would be highly appreciated.